# R make a list of dataframes by subsetting from a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
y<-rep(y, each=10)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

I would like to make a list of dataframes by subsetting by values in the y column. The end result would produce the same output as something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(df[df$y=="a",])
df2 <- data.frame(df[df$y=="b",])
...
df10 <- data.frame(df[df$y=="j",])

list <- list(df1,df2.....df10)
```

... but without all of the repetition. Thanks!

Comment: `split(df, df$y)`

Answer (score 0):

```
split(df, y)
```

.................

Comment: `y not found` ... perhaps `df$y`?